# Python Dash server with waitress

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, plotly-dash, waitress

I have a dashboard application written in Dash framework.
It also has a few Restful API's written using flask.
I am adding flask app to Dash server, as

```
import dash
import flask
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

flask_server = flask.Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__,server=flask_server, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
```

And am running the server as

```
from dashboard import app
from waitress import serve

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.title = 'Litmus'
    app.run_server(debug=False)
    # serve(app,host="0.0.0.0",port=8050)
```

The above code works fine when I am using `app.run_server(debug=False)` but it throws excetion when I use waitress to run the server.
When I use following lines

```
#app.run_server(debug=False)
serve(app,host="0.0.0.0",port=8050)
```

I get following error

```
ERROR:waitress:Exception while serving /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\litmus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\waitress\channel.py", line 397, in service
    task.service()
  File "C:\Users\litmus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\waitress\task.py", line 168, in service
    self.execute()
  File "C:\Users\litmus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\waitress\task.py", line 434, in execute
    app_iter = self.channel.server.application(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'Dash' object is not callable
ERROR:waitress:Exception while serving /favicon.ico
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\litmus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\waitress\channel.py", line 397, in service
    task.service()
  File "C:\Users\litmus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\waitress\task.py", line 168, in service
    self.execute()
  File "C:\Users\litmus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\waitress\task.py", line 434, in execute
    app_iter = self.channel.server.application(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'Dash' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not working because you're passing the Dash app instead of the Flask app to `serve`.

So instead of this:

```
serve(app,host="0.0.0.0",port=8050)
```

pass the Flask app instance like this:

```
serve(app.server, host="0.0.0.0", port=8050)
```